# Error when Splitting an .xml file using java 8

Tags: java, xml

Okay so I am new to coding and have been trying to get this java code to do what I want but so far I have had nothing but problems trying to get it to work correctly.

from what I can tell it gets to this portion of the code:

```
if (str.contains("<TABLE")) {
    tableName = str.split("\'")[1];
}
```

and the code breaks with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at decompose.FileDecompose.main(FileDecompose.java:30)
```

I Tried changing the [1] to a [0] and I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: e:\Games\libconfig_twn\decompose\    <TABLE name='KeyInfo' RowCount='77' TableInfoID = '17' FieldCnt = '4'>.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at decompose.FileDecompose.main(FileDecompose.java:33)
```

am using java 8 up 161

```
package decompose;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileDecompose {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

            // here goes decrypted libconfig file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("I:\\libconfig\\merge\\libconfig.xml");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String str = null;
            int count = 0;
            String tableName = "";
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!str.equals("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>") && !str.contains("<INI TableCount")) {
                    sb.append(str + "\n");
                    if (str.contains("<TABLE")) {
                        tableName = str.split("\'")[1];
                    }
                    if (str.contains("</TABLE>")) {
                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(
                        // here goes decomposed files folder
                        "I:\\libconfig\\decompose\\"+ tableName + ".xml");

                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                        bw.write(sb.toString());
                        bw.close();
                        writer.close();
                        sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    }
                }
            }

            br.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and I have been trying to split my .xml document but so far the script above is not working no matter what modifications I make to it so I am asking for some help.

Here some information about my xml document libconfig.xml 110Mb and here is an example of the xml document cut down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<INI TableCount = '7786' TableInfoCount = '1262'>
<TABLE name='KeyInfo' RowCount='77' TableInfoID = '17' FieldCnt = '4'>
<FIELDINFO Name='Name' IsKey='1' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='EnumName' IsKey='0' DataType='Enum'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='InputKind' IsKey='0' DataType='Enum'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='Modifyer' IsKey='0' DataType='Enum'></FIELDINFO>
<ROW>
<Name><![CDATA[Action]]></Name>
<EnumName>1</EnumName>
<InputKind>216</InputKind>
<Modifyer>0</Modifyer>
</ROW>
</TABLE>
<TABLE name='CharacterInfo' RowCount='2402' TableInfoID = '18' FieldCnt = '16'>
<FIELDINFO Name='ID' IsKey='1' DataType='Enum'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='CommonName' IsKey='0' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='CommonName_Eng' IsKey='0' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='FileName' IsKey='0' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='PartName' IsKey='0' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='IllustName' IsKey='0' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='WalkSpeed' IsKey='0' DataType='float'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='SizeOnStop' IsKey='0' DataType='Enum'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='SizeOnMove' IsKey='0' DataType='Enum'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='RunSpeed' IsKey='0' DataType='float'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='MinAtkRange' IsKey='0' DataType='INT'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='MaxAtkRange' IsKey='0' DataType='INT'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='ChaseRange' IsKey='0' DataType='INT'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='PivotFileName' IsKey='0' DataType='String'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='TransRate' IsKey='0' DataType='INT'></FIELDINFO>
<FIELDINFO Name='HideShadow' IsKey='0' DataType='bool'></FIELDINFO>
<ROW>
<ID>1</ID>
<CommonName><![CDATA[Rabbit]]></CommonName>
<CommonName_Eng><![CDATA[Rabbit]]></CommonName_Eng>
<FileName><![CDATA[data\character\chr001.nri]]></FileName>
<PartName><![CDATA[data\part\chr001_]]></PartName>
<IllustName><![CDATA[ ]]></IllustName>
<WalkSpeed>0.000000</WalkSpeed>
<SizeOnStop>2</SizeOnStop>
<SizeOnMove>0</SizeOnMove>
<RunSpeed>0.000000</RunSpeed>
<MinAtkRange>50</MinAtkRange>
<MaxAtkRange>70</MaxAtkRange>
<ChaseRange>300</ChaseRange>
<PivotFileName><![CDATA[data\character\chr001.pvt]]></PivotFileName>
<TransRate>0</TransRate>
<HideShadow>0</HideShadow>
</ROW>
</TABLE>
</INI>
```

okay so I want to split my xml from `<TABLE to </TABLE>` then search for name='???' in `<TABLE name='KeyInfo' RowCount='77' TableInfoID = '17' FieldCnt = '4'>` and create a file example: 
00001_KeyInfo.xml

00002_CharacterInfo.xml

and so on...

there are around 11,000 tables that need to be split and each table has different contents and needs to have utf-8 character encoding so yeah this has been so hard for me being new to coding and I hope some one can help.

Comment: From a quick glance, I would say that you should look into using an XML parser.  Don't use base string operations or even regex to parse XML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why it's failing, but this is a dreadful way to tackle this task. Never use string matching on XML, always use a proper XML parser.

This job is so easy in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="TABLE">
  <xsl:result-document href="{@name}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, but i did have to trial and error some of it.

Comment: I never used xslt before so I had to do some research and I went with using saxon but I had some errors with the xsl code not keeping the structure of the xml but I found out I can add method="xml" indent="yes" and it fixed that. also how hard would it be to do the reverse? and search for the 11,000 .xml files and merge them into 1 .xml file again?

Comment: Just noticed all the <![CDATA[ was removed :( there are around 3,000 different portions that use it and it all needs to stay intact so how would I preserver it all?

Comment: Merging the files is as simple as `<xsl:copy-of select="collection($URI)"/>`. As for CDATA, The XSLT/XPath data model considers `<a>Rabbit</a>` and `<a><![CDATA[Rabbit]]></a>` to be exactly the same animal, but if you really want to treat them as different, you could preprocess/postprocess using Lexev.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java xml api like so

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    String file = "/home/william/Documents/test.xml";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
    Document xml = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(fis);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//TABLE";
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node table = nodeList.item(i);
        String name = table.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent();
        String content = toContent(table);
        save(content, name);
    }
}

private static String toContent(Node node) {
    // your implementation here
    return null;
}

private static void save(String content, String name) {
    // TODO implement
}
```